# Using the PykTok module on a EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, module, keyerror

I'm trying to use the PykTok module on an ec2 instance. It's set up to work (I've the right versions of everything)
When I execute my script I got this error :

```
KeyError: 'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS'. Check if the TikTok API response format has changed.
```

The script it self is not important but I'd like to know if there is a way to use Pyktok on a server. (and if not if there are alternatives)
Ty ^^

Comment: The Error message after the KeyError : "DBUS_SESSION_ADRESS" is not important it's something I setted up temporarly

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use request from website that dl tiktoks to get them from a server. Using Pyktok is useless